# MediaMetadataRetriever .getFrameAtTime(long, option) crashing

Tags: android, eclipse

I've got a loop where I'm trying to extract a frame from a video every 1/10th of a second. But after 19 frames (1.9s of the video), I get the following error on Logcat:

```
01-22 11:59:15.498: E/OMXCodec(38): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Timed out waiting for output buffers: 0/0
01-22 11:59:15.598: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(38): failed to capture a video frame
01-22 11:59:15.598: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(572): getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
01-22 11:59:15.598: D/AndroidRuntime(572): Shutting down VM
01-22 11:59:15.598: W/dalvikvm(572): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
01-22 11:59:15.608: E/AndroidRuntime(572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 11:59:15.608: E/AndroidRuntime(572): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
File videoPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.mp4");
String video = videoPath.getAbsolutePath();
MediaMetadataRetriever vidFile = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
vidFile.setDataSource(video);

//Create folder to store images
String storageFolder = "/Storage";
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File newFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + storageFolder);
newFolder.mkdir();

String value = vidFile.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long vidLength = (Long.parseLong(value)/1000); //Returns milliseconds - divide by 1,000
//Video length = 30037ms - result is 30.037s

for(int i = 0; i <= 10*vidLength; i++, image++) //10*vidLength since I'm getting frames every 1/10th sec
{
    Bitmap bmp = vidFile.getFrameAtTime(100000*i, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
    String imagename = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%03d", image);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + storageFolder + File.separator + imagename + ".png");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();

    //Don't seem to make a difference one way or the other
    bytes.flush(); 
    bytes.close();  
}
```

Like I said, it should get ~300 frames, but only manages to extract 19 frames before crashing, but I don't see why the NULL pointer error is happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually i'd tried your above code to get all frames from video file but i get only the first frames repeatedly.my duration of video is 127040(2:07sec) divided the video to 32 frames can view all 32 images but all were same images i'd tried a lot to fix it with getFrameAtTime(potions) but no use at all exactly i don't knoe where it goes wrong so can you help me by your full source code should i include any thing in AndroidManifest

Comment: i find your mistake @zodac .. see my answer below. you are dividing by 1000 instead of multiplying.. now you understand the reason of Null Pointer

Comment: This is still an issue, any new advice on this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) lib instead of MediaMetadataRetriever?

Also, from this line on your logcat:

> 01-22 11:59:15.598: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(572): getFrameAtTime:
>   videoFrame is a NULL pointer

I would try making it log every line of the for loop, like Log.d("MyApp","Param of getFrameAtTime"+(100000*i));

I know you already know which frame is the problem (19/20), but just to see what happens with that variable before becoming a null pointer (maybe you could work with Long i instead of int i?).

Also, did you try the suggestion above to use MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC instead of OPTION_CLOSEST?

Answer (score 1):

I get similar behavior on my Evo V running Android 4.0: the first six frames of my test video convert just fine, then I start getting null pointers back, even if I construct a new MediaMetadataRetriever to try again.

My logs also show: "MediaMetadataRetriever server died!"

There is a way to avoid this problem and depending on what you are trying to do it may be suitable: pass MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC instead of OPTION_CLOSEST.

In my tests, the crashes always go away when I use OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC.

This is not much help for my application, because I actually do need frames at very close intervals, not just the designated "sync frames." But it may be more acceptable in yours.

Comment: Same situation actually - I'm looking for specific frames, not the keyframes.

Good to know it's not just me though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I find your mistake you are dividing instead of multiplying..
Converting milli to micro requires multiplying by 1000 whereas you are doing division...

Get the duration of video using MediaPlayer..

```
 file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myvideo.mp4");
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            int duration = mp.getDuration();// it gives duration in milliseconds 
            mp.release();
```

multiply it with `duration*1000`

loop until the

```
     for(int i=0 ;i <5; i++)
                {
                  if(looper < duration *1000)
                  {
                      ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(ids_of_images[i]);


imageView.setImageBitmap(retriever.getFrameAtTime(looper,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST));

                        looper +=1000000;  
                  }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is reported in android bug database as [MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime() failing/crashing](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24300).  This issue has been closed as obsolete.  I came across it on a Tesco HUDL 1.0 (HT7S3) running Android 4.2.2.

Adding the following re-try allowed my code to work.

```
        if( bmp == null){
            mMediaData = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mMediaData.setDataSource( /* same parameters as before */ );
            bmp = mMediaData.getFrameAtTime( /* same parameters */ );
        }
```

It is only earlier versions of Android I have seen this on in my testing, and from the "obsolete" close of the bug, it is something fixed in more recent versions.

As such the work-around where the media Retriever is recreated before subsequent re-queries, is probably the best that can be done.

On my device re-building mediaRetriever takes about 3 seconds, getting a bitmap takes .1s, so I can't really afford to build it each time.

Answer (score 0):

An OPTION_CLOSEST bug was reported, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193194

Google response on August 31, 2016

Hi,
The development team has fixed the issue that you have reported and it will be available in a future build 
Thanks
Status: FutureRelease